# Where did Arya get the face?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the season 6 finale we see that

> Arya Stark used a different face to get close to Walder Frey and assassinate him.

She wasn't allowed to use faces from the hall of faces. Is there any evidence she stole the face or killed somebody? If so, do we know the person the face belonged to?

Comment: Related question from M & TV.SE [Why can Arya still use the faces?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/56123/why-can-arya-still-use-the-faces)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This event never happened in the books so your books tag is meaningless in this regard. As for the show, As of now, we do not know where did she get that face. Right now it would be just speculation.

There are following possibilities:

1. She killed some woman and took her face
2. She stole it from House of Black and White
3. As suggested by [Kl78](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/48639/kl78), She may have found a corpse and carved its face off. She may not have killed her after all.

### Did she kill some person?

It is a possibility but it is also unlikely. Arya has only killed people who were either on her hit-list or were trying to kill her. She refused to kill lady Crane even though she knew that would mean she failed her tests. Therefore it is unlikely she killed some innocent person.

### Did she steal it?

This one is more likely than the other. Arya killed the Waif and put her face in the House of Black and white. Jaqen only entered after Arya had finished putting the face on the wall therefore we do not know if she actually did what I believe she did.

### Did she find it?

It is plausible but less likely. The odds of finding corpse of a good looking young woman just lying out there on the road are very slim. She needed face of a such a woman to find entrance into the castle in disguise of a serving woman.

Lord Walder Frey did not recognize her so that might mean she must have been let in that day only due to her looks and because help would be needed in kitchens to feed the Lannister guests. (Although Lord Walder’s advanced age must be taken into account here, especially how he can’t tell his grandchildren apart sometimes or mothers of his children).

Good looking people get away with things average and bad looking people don’t usually do. Finding entry into a heavily guarded castle hosting very important people is one of those things.

### Do we know her?

No we do not know whose face it was or if it is in any way important to the story.

Comment: Another option would be that she got the face from a person which was already dead, not killed by her but by someone else or accident/natural dead.

Comment: But if she stole the face from the House of Black and White wouldn't she become blind again?

Comment: @Lyrion Hmm why would that happen?

Comment: I thought she became blind because she wore a face without being a faceless man.

Comment: This raises a whole slew of questions about "Mission Impossible."  @DC - I think the blindness was punishment for taking a life that was not named, on her own. Think it was induced by something in her drink, which is why she hesitated later when offered a drink by Jaquen.

Comment: Exactly what Andrew said.

Comment: "If she took one face, she would not be technically stealing because she put another one back in its place" Not true. Failing to kill lady Crane left the House short a face *it was owed*. Jaqen said either Crane or Arya's face would be put on the wall (that one way or another, a new face would be added). It turned out that the Waif's face was a third option Jaqen left out, but sealing a face would undo that balance Arya created to spare herself.

Comment: @CircleSquared Ah Cheers, corrected

Comment: Another option is that it was just a regular mask. Watch how she removes it, by reaching under the chin vs how the faceless men "palm the face".

Comment: I like to the that was the face in the slot that Ayra put the Waif's face in...

Comment: @Aegon "Lord Walder Frey did not recognize her so that means she must have been let in that day only due to her looks and because help would be needed" Given how old Frey is and how many kids he has, and his general temperament, I doubt he is in charge of hiring staff or that he knows all of the staff in his castle. So it is possible Arya was impersonating someone who regularly worked there, but that would again imply she killed that girl, which is out of character for her.

Comment: @childcat15 Hah you are correct. The filthy old codger can't often tell his grandchildren apart or mothers of his children.

Comment: I assume there’s no significance to the capitalization of “she,” but if there is mea culpa and feel free to rollback.

Comment: @Adamant No there isn't. Just sloppy writing job on my part. Thanks!